# state of affairs vs situation

Tags: word-usage

According to multiple dictionaries, **state of affairs** means the same as **situation**, so can I use either of them in the following sentence?

*Overall, the elderly were least vulnerable to poverty, while the opposite **state of affairs** was witnessed for single people who hadn’t reached their old age.*

Comment: You can use it, but it's a bit old-fashioned and formal.

Comment: "was witnessed" is also old-fashioned; are you trying to write to a word count? You could replace "the opposite state of affairs was witnessed" with "the opposite was true".

Comment: No, I'm not. It's nearly impossible for non-native speakers like me to know which word/phrase is old-fashioned. I just learn them here and there and sometimes when I write, some of them come to my mind.

Comment: State of Affairs is perfectly acceptable in the context of a political or diplomatic discussion. Your example is more in line of social sciences where you are comparing groups to arrive at a distinction. Here, "situation" is more appropriate. As for the use of witness, you are not normally present when making these comparisons. You are making observations concerning the groups.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do I have to be present to use witness? As far as I know, I can write: _"The last century witnessed a sharp fall in sales,"_ so writing _"A sharp fall in sales was witnessed in the last century."_ should be fine as well, shouldn't it? If that's the case, I haven't seen why using _witnessed_ in my original sentence is inappropriate, besides the fact that it's old-fashioned as Stuart pointed out.

Comment: You will often hear in speech people say: Well, that's a fine state of affairs. Meaning: a real mess. It is idiomatic but your usage sounds forced and awkward.

Comment: @Ken Adams "Out of curiosity, do I have to be present to use witness? As far as I know, I can write: "The last century witnessed a sharp fall in sales,"" Your example personifies "last century". It was the witness.

Answer (score 2):

"Situation" is a simple word "for State of affairs". But both can be omitted, and the sentence can be shortened without losing meaning:

Overall, the elderly were least vulnerable to poverty, while the opposite was true for non-elderly singles.

In almost all writing, shorter and simpler is better than longer and more complex.

Comment: state of affairs is not capitalized.

Comment: So I can also say, "Overall, the elderly have decreased in number in the last century, while the opposite trend was true for babies," can't I?

Comment: Yes, I think "the opposite" is clear in your sentence.